# Variable length javascript table access

Tags: javascript

Assume I have the following:

```
strA = "/ItemA/Item1/Item2/"
dataA = "A Data"

strB = "/ItemA/Item1/Item2/Item3/"
dataB = "B Data"

table = { "ItemA" : { 
            "Item1" : { 
              "Item2": { 
                "Item3" : { ... }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

The string contains the items in the table (which are subtable keys) and then the accompanying data would need to be stored there.

Assuming I could have a string of variable length (i.e. could go all the way to "Item7"), is there a simple way to access the table?

An iterative loop won't work (I think):

```
stringPartsA = strA.split("/"); //["ItemA", "Item1", "Item2"] (assuming I've also removed the ""'s)
for (var i = 0; i < stringPartsA.length; i++){
   table[stringPartsA[i]]... //This doesn't work
}
//Need a way to access like table[stringParts[0]][stringParts[1]][stringParts[2]]...[stringParts[N-1]]
```

I searched and couldn't find a similar question, wondering if there's a solution (without modifying the structure of the string or table...).

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote, cool anonymous SOer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is something like:

```
var out = table;
strA.split("/").filter(function(el) {
    return el !== "";
}).forEach(function(el) {
    out = out[el];
});
//out now stores the object you want
```

Explanation:

- `split` splits the string into an array of strings splitting by "/" character
- `filter` filters out the empty strings at the start and end of said array
- `forEach` loops through the filtered array and changes out at each loop to navigate further into the `table` object

Comment: Great answer! Wasn't thinking about just storing a reference to the point in the table where I wanted to be - makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

I think your iterative solution is mostly there...

```
stringPartsA = strA.split("/");
var currentLevel = table; 
for (var i = 0; i < stringPartsA.length; i++){
   var token = stringPartsA[i];
   if (!token) continue; // handle leading or trailing slashes
   currentLevel = currentLevel[token];
}
return currentLevel;
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Nick, great answer! I think both you and Shane have very similar answers, but it looks like Shane beat you by a minute - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

ShaneQful's answer is good but it can be further simplified. Less code and no state.

```
var result = path.split('/').reduce(function (result, key) {
    return key ? result[key] : result;
}, table);
```

Note Lo-Dash or Underscore can be used instead of the native [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Also, I haven't looked much into Lo-Dash or Underscore... interesting (and seemingly quite useful) libraries. Also, what do you mean by no state? Forgive my ignorance...

Comment: I mean that there is no external variable (`out` in ShaneQful's answer) that exposes the current state of the algorithm. The version I propose is stateless. State is *generally* something you want to avoid (see [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)).

Comment: Understood - this is a great answer! Modified my code to use this... thanks Hugo!